# How to create dropdown for <li> using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make drop down for one `<li>` element

```
<div class="head-nav">
                <span class="menu"></span>
                <ul class="cl-effect-15">
                    <li><a href="index.php" data-hover="HOME">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php" data-hover="CONTACT">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-hover=" "> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="3" data-hover=" "> </a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-hover="More option" tabindex="-1">More options</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#" data-hover=" ">one</a></li>
                                <li><a href="3" data-hover=" ">two</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="logout.php" data-hover="logout">logout</a></li>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

but sub menu doesn't opens

using `Bootstrap v3.1.1`

**NOTE** : even adding after `jquery` also doesn't works

Comment: for the code to work `data-toggle="dropdown"` is very important , without that , your dropdown , will probably not work . The bootstrap.js uses `data-toggle="dropdown"` as a hook , to understand that , thats the element that needs to be toggled !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik do i need to add `bootstrap.js` i just added `jquery` only

Comment: ABOSULTLY :D , you need to add bootstap.js files :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

In your code, you miss class "dropdown" for li tag.
For correct dropdown, you have to use this sintax:

```
<li class="dropdown">
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Item Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<!--- Put your menu-item here -->
  </ul>
</li>
```

You can refer the Bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

The issue is causing by the missing of `data-toggle="dropdown"` in tag a

Comment: even after adding drop doesn't opens

Comment: You miss also data-toggle on a tag. Check you sintax

Comment: Can you fiddle full code? Have some kind of error (maybe a missing file source)

Comment: @MTS , this is not the correct answer , Please edit your answer to mention that `data-toggle` is whats causing the issue !

Comment: @MTS can i do this without `bootstrap.js`

Comment: @romman in general to use bootstrap you need of css and js, or something may didn't works. In this case you dont have to inizialize the js function to dropdown the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you search this solution: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kedivoqaya/)

For example:
You need add the content: attr(data-hover); on your before element.
HTML:

```
<li class="HOVER"><a href="#" data-hover="More option" tabindex="-1">More options</a>
```

CSS:

```
.HOVER {
  border: solid 7px #000;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.HOVER:hover a:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  color: red;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -7px;
  right: -7px;
  padding: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the the following attributes:

```
class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
```

and those attributes go on the element you want to be the "Hook" for the dropdown list.

Sample markup below:

```
 <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#lala" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
                   Java 
                   <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
                   <li><a href="#lala1" role="option">jmeter</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#lala2" role="option">EJB</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#lala3" role="option">Jasper Report</a></li>
                   <li class="divider"></li>
                   <li><a href="#" role="option">Separated link</a></li>
                   <li class="divider"></li>
                   <li><a href="#" role="option">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
```

### Edit

Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voc70a2c/1/); notice how if you remove `data-toggle="dropdown"`, the code won't work . :)

Comment: drop down not appearing